# How to customize Spring Security Shiro Grails plugin Login Logout functionality?

Tags: grails, spring-security

This seems like something that should be pretty easy, but I am unable to customize the Login (login/authenticate) and Logout functionality of spring-security-shrio that is pre-built.

I would like to do things like add a login counter, or login log so when a user logs in I log who they are and additional information like an ip address.

Also, I went to the source and found the LoginController, copied that but noticed that there is no authenticate method within that controller.

I am upgrading an application from Grails version 2.4.4 to Grails 3+. Where is the code that is generated? Any guidance would be most appreciated.

Comment: http://plugins.grails.org/plugin/grails/spring-security-shiro was under the impress shiro worked under grails2 but remained broken for 3

Comment: Yeah, currently not supported in 3. There is a plugin though that bridges shiro and spring security in Grails 3 that I am working with.

Answer (score 0):

Not Shiro specific but you can add a login directory to views then add your own auth.gsp to handle logging in.

Note that a number of the parameter names changed from Grails 2 to 3 e.g. j_username to username see [here](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/v3/index.html#newInV3).

Here's a bootstrap styled one I converted from a Grails 2 to 3 app recently:

```
<html>
<head>
   <meta name='layout' content='main'/>
   <title><g:message code="springSecurity.login.title"/></title>
</head>

<body>
<div id='login' class="maincontentdiv">

      <g:render template="/templates/alerts"/>

      <form action='${postUrl}' method='POST' id='loginForm' class='form-horizontal' autocomplete='off'>

         <fieldset>
            <legend><g:message code="springSecurity.login.header"/></legend>

            <div class="form-group">
               <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="username">
                  <g:message code="springSecurity.login.username.label" default="Username" />
                  <span class="required-indicator">*</span>
               </label>
               <div class="col-md-4"> 
                  <input type='text' class='form-control' name='username' id='username'/>
               </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
               <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="password">
                  <g:message code="springSecurity.login.password.label" default="Password" />
                  <span class="required-indicator">*</span>
               </label>
               <div class="col-md-4"> 
                  <input type='password' class='form-control' name='password' id='password'/>
               </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
               <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="submit"></label>
               <div class="col-md-4">
                  <input type='submit' id="submit" class='btn btn-primary' value='${message(code: "springSecurity.login.button")}'/>
               </div>
            </div>
         </fieldset>
      </form>
</div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
   <!--
   (function() {
      document.forms['loginForm'].elements['username'].focus();
   })();
   // -->
</script>
</body>
</html>
```